# how to access nested data by nesting fetch calls?

Tags: json, react-native, nested, fetch

I'm having trouble understanding the best approach to this.

My goal is to display nested data.

I use fetch on this url - https://horizons-json-cors.s3.amazonaws.com/products.json

which takes me to a page that contains json. inside the json is 3 urls. each url contains the data that I need to get to.

So far, I've accessed the first layer, and now have an array of the item urls. I guess I don't understand how to fetch the data while im inside the outter fetch call.

Here's my code thus far (the result is an array of urls, where each url contains the data I need.) :

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Fetch');
    fetch("https://horizons-json-cors.s3.amazonaws.com/products.json")
    .then((resp) => (resp.json()))
    .then((json) => {
      var productUrlArr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        productUrlArr.push(json[i].url);
      }
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error', err);
    });
  }
```

If you guys could help me out and really walk through how to access the next level of data, I would really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you put the response of the API call below?

Comment: Is this an API you own? If so, it sounds to me that you should change the API so that you actually return the data for the products instead of a link to ANOTHER json file. Otherwise, it will be very inefficient, since you'll have to get the first JSON file, then iterate through each element and then make an _additional_ call PER ITEM.

Comment: it's not an API that I own. It's an exercise from my school that's supposed to teach us how to work with nested data. I realize it's inefficient but I still have to learn how to work with it. My problem is figuring out how to iterate and call on each item / url while inside the outer fetch call

Comment: Ok, but does it return a response? you can print your response with a `console.log` and publish it as well.

Comment: yes @MateoGuzmán. it returns a response of an array of objects. Each object is single value - key pair of 'url' and an individual url as stated above. My problem is that it's not clear to me how to loop through these urls and call fetch on each one.

Comment: Perfect. Please put the response in your question, with it we can help you easier. :) @aglaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little error in your code.

It's missing `})` before `.catch`

With it you can use your data in the array.

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Fetch');
    fetch("https://horizons-json-cors.s3.amazonaws.com/products.json")
    .then((resp) => (resp.json()))
    .then((json) => {
      var productUrlArr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        productUrlArr.push(json[i].url);
      }
      console.log(productUrlArr);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error', err);
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can Fetch Data for Inner URLs this way too,

```
// 1. Outer Fetch call initiated here
fetch("https://horizons-json-cors.s3.amazonaws.com/products.json")
 .then(res => {
    return res.json()
 })
 .then(res => {

    // 2. array for storing url's retrieved from response
    var urlArray = []

    if (res.length > 0) {

        // 3. Push url inside urlArray
        res.map(data => urlArray.push(data.url))
    }

    // 4. an array of urls
    return urlArray
 })
 .then(urls => {

    // Return an promise which will return "JSON response" array for all URLs.
    // Promise.all means “Wait for these things” not “Do these things”.

    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
        // Take url fetch response, return JSON response
        return fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    }
    ))
 })
 .then(res => {
    // Store all objects into array for later use
    var objArr = res; return objArr
  })
//.then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It simple. First get all the url first like you did. Then map and pass it into `Promise.all`.

```
fetch("https://horizons-json-cors.s3.amazonaws.com/products.json")
  .then((resp) => (resp.json()))
  .then((json) => {
    Promise.all(json.map(product =>
        fetch(product.url).then(resp => resp.text())
    )).then(texts => {
        // catch all the data
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
  });
```